# Expose docker port on Amazon ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I'm trying to deploy application which opens two ports; one is a simple http server another is used for app to communicate with other instances and join in clusters. You guessed it, it's elasticsearch.

So using Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.js or maybe some other configuration files which I can add in distribution how is it possible to tell EB to map port 9300 to private networking interface?

My current Dockerfile has

```
EXPOSE 9200 9300
```

But from [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html#create_deploy_docker_image_dockerfile) is said that EB will only attach nginx reverse proxy to first port and nothing said about how to map other ports without nginx

Thanks

**UPDATE #1:**

Using *.ebextensions* it is possible to execute any shell command. I am trying to map port via iptables, however still have some issues.

**UPDATE #2:**
After two days of mining knowledge and digging es cave I was able to map ports to host machine and setup ES discovery. However, ES still don't want to create cluster, this time due to

```
disconnecting from [...] due to explicit disconnect call
```

**UPDATE #3:**
I was not able to make ElasticSearch to work with EBT Docker containers, however I made it work without docker directly on EBT instance. Here is working config
https://github.com/vladmiller/elasticsearch-beanstalk

Comment: I'd recommend moving to Elastic Container Service - you'll get the customization that you need at a cost of reduced simplicity for auto scaling and deployments. I tried pigeonholing my own app with EBS myself before I switched.

Comment: @sjagr at this point I already figured out most of the issues with EB, however now I have ES specific issues

Comment: @VladMiller Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into a similar issue, although without Docker/EB.  It was working fine before I upgraded from ES 1.7.4 to 2.1.1.

Comment: @Zenexer yes I did, but without Docker. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to make ElasticSearch to discover other nodes on EBT Docker environment, however I made it work using instance itself

Working config
https://github.com/vladmiller/elasticsearch-beanstalk

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch binds to localhost by default now (2.x).  Use these settings in your elasticsearch.yml to bind to a physical interface.  Keep in mind that making your Elasticsearch server publicly accessible to the internet is insecure, bordering on suicidal, so be sure you have a good firewall and are only listening on a LAN interface.

```
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: _non_loopback_
```

If you're using the `cloud-aws` plugin for automatic discovery on AWS/EC2, you may want to automatically choose your VPC interface's IP address:

```
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: _ec2_
```

It's possible that `_ec2_` may be deprecated at some point and replaced with `_ec2:privateIpv4_`.

Sources:

- [Network Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html)
- [EC2 Discovery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.1/cloud-aws-discovery.html#cloud-aws-discovery-network-host)

Comment: That was completely different problem, here is the working config for EBT and Docker https://github.com/vladmiller/elasticsearch-beanstalk